# TypeAhead: error message instead of suggestions data

Tags: typeahead, empty-list

I am using `typeahead` library, it's fetching the data successfully. But not loading the data into the suggestions list, instead its showing the `unable to find any company that match current query` every time.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#js-typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
}, {
    displayKey: ['title'],
    source: function(keywords, result) {
        ajaxRequest({
            url: '{{ route("admin.companies.auto-complete") }}',
            dateType: 'json',
            data: {
                keywords: keywords,
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                result($.map(response, function(data) {
                    return {
                        'title': data.title,
                        'token': data.token,
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
                'unable to find any company that match current query',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: function(data) {
            return '<a href="' + data.token + '">' + data.title + '</a>';
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the fetched data

[image: Here is the fetched data]

---

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]: Here is my final code...

```js
$('.js-typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
}, {
    displayKey: 'title',
    source: (new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '{{ route("admin.{$parent['route']}.auto-complete") }}',
            prepare: function (keywords, settings) {
                return $.extend({}, settings, {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        keywords: keywords,
                        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    })
                });
            }
        }
    })),
    templates: {
        empty: '<div class="empty">No result found</div>',
        suggestion: function (data) {
            return '<div>' + data.title + '</div>';
        }
    },
}).on('typeahead:asyncrequest', function(event) {
    $('.js-typeahead').before('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin loading"></i>');
}).on('typeahead:asyncreceive', function(event) {
    $('.js-typeahead').prev('.loading').remove();
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, selection) {
    // window.location.href = selection.token;
});
```

I hope this may come in handy for someone...

Answer (score 0):

You're code is practically correct. And the best thing is that you can also get the result without using bloodhound.

from the initial code you state, you are calling it synchronously. thats why it does not yield any result.from typeahead docs. here is the highlight

> Expected to be a function with the signature (query, syncResults, asyncResults). syncResults should be called with suggestions computed synchronously and asyncResults should be called with suggestions computed asynchronously (e.g. suggestions that come for an AJAX request)

so your initial code part

```
source: function(keywords, result) {
    ajaxRequest({
        url: '{{ route("admin.companies.auto-complete") }}',
        dateType: 'json',
        data: {
            keywords: keywords,
            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            result($.map(response, function(data) {
                return {
                    'title': data.title,
                    'token': data.token,
                };
            }));
        }
    });
},
```

are running synchronously, and because you are fetching data from ajax, you should make it asynchronously like this (i added asyncresult)

```
source: function(keywords, result, asyncresult) {
    ajaxRequest({
        url: '{{ route("admin.companies.auto-complete") }}',
        dateType: 'json',
        data: {
            keywords: keywords,
            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            asyncresult($.map(response, function(data) {
                return {
                    'title': data.title,
                    'token': data.token,
                };
            }));
        }
    });
},
```

hope it helps!